# How to capture distribution metrics of the redis cluster?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer

We have a redis cluster containing multiple redis instances. We also have a spring boot app that read from/write to this cluster. Now we want to use micrometer/prometheus/grafana to capture operation distribution metrics of the cluster (for example, this cluster have 3 instances and the counter metrics should show me 1k request to instance 1, 900 to instance 2 and 0 to instance 3 since instance 3 was not running).

I would like to get your idea how to archive this requirement. Please help!

```
Spring boot version: 2.3.9-RELEASE
Redisson version: 3.15.0
```

Comment: The version you are using is very old and not supported anymore. You can instrument your redis client using a Timer.

Comment: Hi @JonatanIvanov thank you for your comment. Could you help to provide more infomation? "The version you are using is very old..." you mean redisson or spring boot? "You can instrument your redis client..." can you provide me a snip of code?

Comment: I meant Boot: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support also, I forgot that instrumentation is available starting from Redison 3.21.0: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/4976 you will need Spring Boot 3 for that.

Comment: I still cannot get your point about instrumentation. How Observation API give me the distribution of the redis cluster? I want to get some thing like: 1k request to instance 1, 900 to instance 2 and 0 to instance 3 since instance 3 was not running

Please help to provide some code snip. Thank you